# Compare two Pandas dataframe for addition of any new rows with respect to the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I am creating parser of changes on pseudo-table web application to push notification if there any rows were added.

**Mechanic of the pseudo-table:** Table on the website changes per some time and adds new rows. This page is highly dynamic and sometimes changes the existing rows. Pseudo-table automatically assigns id respecting to the sorting mechanic. So to explain precisely, sorting algorithm is alphabetic so guy ID named Adam would be 1, Bob = 2, Coul=3. But if they will add person with name Caul it would become ID 3, when Coul would become 4. This ruins all the methods I have tried so far.

I am trying right now to compare two Pandas dataframe to detect row addition and return new-added rows. I do *not want* to return **existing** rows that were changed. I tried by using concat and removing duplicates but this results in duplicate rows where there was any minor change in the data.

***TL;DR EXAMPLE***

Input

```
d1 = {'#': [1, 2, 3], 'Name': ['James Bourne', 'Steve Johns', 'Steve Jobs']}
d2 = {'#': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Name': ['James Bourne', 'Steve Jobs', 'Great Guy', 'Steve Johns']}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
# ... code
```

Output should be

```
3     Great Guy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a simpler solution:

```
df2[ ~df2.Name.isin(df1.Name)].dropna()
```

Output:

```
   #       Name
2  3  Great Guy
```

Answer (score 0):

merge dfs with `(how = outer)`, then compare merged df to list of original Names

```
>>> merged = pd.merge(df_1,df_2,on='Name', how = 'outer')
>>> [x for x in enumerate(merged.Name) if x[1] not in list(df_1.Name)]
```

Results in: `[(3, 'Great Guy')]`

Answer (score 0):

I found out the subset parameter in the drop_duplicates.

```
d1 = {'#': [1, 2, 3], 'Name': ['James Bourne', 'Steve Johns', 'Steve Jobs']}
d2 = {'#': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Name': ['James Bourne', 'Steve Jobs', 'Great Guy', 'Steve Johns']}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
df_1 = df_1.set_index('#')
df_2 = df_2.set_index('#')
df = pd.concat([df_1,df_2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'], keep=False)
df
```

results in

```
    Name
#   
3   Great Guy
```

This solves my question.